# Ubuntu server 14.04 internet connection problem

Tags: networking, internet, ip, vmware-workstation

I installed Ubuntu server 14.04 on VMware workstation. I need to set IP manually so,  network connection has set to Bridged on VMware. 
I followed the instructions on https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html to set up an IP address.

first, the file `/etc/network/interfaces` changed as follows:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.11
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-nameservers 4.2.2.4 8.8.8.8
```

second, following line was added to  `/etc/hosts`

```
10.0.0.11     myserver
```

the file `/etc/resolv.conf` has been updated like this:

```
nameserver 4.2.2.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

and then rebooted the system to accept the changes.
I can ping to default gateway 10.0.0.1, host OS 10.0.0.102, and another computer 10.0.0.2 on the local network, but pinging the internet does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered something similar to this on another question. I had same issues sharing the internet connection from the Host to the Guest. I tried NAT, Bridging and nothing worked until I clicked on "Auto Ethernet" under the wifi icon in upper right taskbar area. One click and the internet connected right away. Of course, networking was already enabled.